# Delete a registry value using a CAB installer

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, registry, cab

Is it possible to delete a registry key using a CAB installer that is generated using VS2005?

The CAB is targeted at Windows CE 6.

---

Edit:

I did find this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=415990, but I was hoping to find a way to do it using VS2005 or VS2008 and in an easier way. 
(I did not even start to try the instructions on that post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. you can..
But u need to mention the proper registry value..
see this [link](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsphone/archive/2009/08/11/using-custom-icons-in-windows-mobile-6-5.aspx) for more info..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I could not find in the post anything that mentions the removal of registry values.

Comment: u please checkout the code of link http://windowsteamblog.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/windowsphone/sms%20intercept.zip.

reffer the creation of .cab using dynamic method.. here you can do

Comment: This is in fact the method. The exact link I needed was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx
Adding this Dll enables to do in code what the wizard does not supply.

Comment: I might have marked this as the "Answer" too early. For some reason the code in the added Dll does not execute. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: Hey it works perfectly,
can you tell what problem are you getting.

Comment: I found it - I did not edit the Dll Project's setting to input the export file. Basically in the link they miss out completely the step of defining the entry functioning in an export file.