# Error installing cab file on Windows CE

Tags: windows-ce, cab, cabwiz

I'm having trouble using macros in my .inf file that I'm using to create my cab, specifically when setting the `InstallDir` string.  If I do something like this:

```
InstallDir=\<PathToProgramFiles>\MyAppName
```

then everything works fine.  However, if I do this:

```
InstallDir=%CE1%\MyAppName
```

then I get the following error when trying to install the cab (double tapping it on my device): "MyAppName was not installed successfully.  Please run Setup again."

This only seems to apply to the built-in macro strings.  I can use `%AppName%` without any problems.  Maybe there is some registry setting that isn't properly set that would normally resolve the `%CE1%` macro?

Any ideas about what is going on?

Edit: My device doesn't have a `\Program Files` directory.  It seems the `%CE1%` macro always resolves to that path and if the `InstallDir` specified in the inf file doesn't exist (with the exception of the last directory portion then the install fails.  Manually creating `\Program Files` fixed the issue.  Since a lot of the devices I'm working with have different paths for their Program Files directory, is there a generic way to get the installer to default to the actual Program Files dir?  I guess my only other option is to not specify a path and force the user to choose one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in [this](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/wince_cab_format/) link you can find the shortcuts and their meaning (the %C..%), goto appendix B. [The Windows CE5 MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms934880.aspx) link.

You can add a [Setup Dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) to your CAB installaer that will check the directory structure and will create a folder in case it does not exist. You may find [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554467/delete-a-registry-value-using-a-cab-installer) question useful.

**A warning:** If you are targeting regular Windows CE devices, beware where you place the files as it can be to a RAM based file system and then the files will disappear after reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think my problem is that ultimately the macros as defined are meant to be used for localization purposes and not the same as looking up the real path (e.g. SHGetSpecialFolder()).  I think I'm ultimately going to have to build my own installer that properly deals with these differences.  It doesn't look like a custom setup DLL will allow me to tweak the install path...